# USB Host device

Tags: usb, host, atmega

I am looking at creating a USB host devices to talk to a standalone printer.
Basically my devices would feed out commands to the USB chip and the pritner would print it without interaction of a PC.

What chips would you recommend for the USB/MCU? 
I am leaning towards an ATMEGA micro with a Vinculum USB interface.
Would it be easier to use a all in one chip or have a seperate MCU and USB chip?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used one, but I'd look into the [AT90USB1287](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/Products/Product_card.asp?part_id=3875) chip.  It even comes in an handy evaluation board called the [AT90USBKey](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/products/tools_card.asp?tool_id=3879).  While the chip itself is supposed to be able to act as a [USB-OTG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go) Host, it isn't clear to me that the demo board supports that.

Comment: The UsbKey has a special cable that is marked with usb otg, so I think it can... (but I never tried it)

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use an MCU with USB OTG to drive the printer. It will be a lot cheaper than using a separate chip like the Vinculum.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [LUFA](http://www.fourwalledcubicle.com/LUFA.php), it has some support for USB host on MCUs. However, I expect that the printer driver you create might end up being tied to one particular model of printer.

Depending on your project requirements, it might be easier to drive a serial or parallel printer interface than USB.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is primarily with Microchip, but Atmel may have chips with integrated USB as well. Microchip has a few products with integrated USB. You'll want one that supports USB on-the-go or embedded host. Microchip also provides the USB host stack that will help get you up and running with a few basic device classes.

Answer (score 0):

Atmel provide host and device firmware for their AVR32B family of processors.  These have built in USB 2.0 OTG hardware.  The EVK1101 development board is a good hardware target and the AVR studio is a free GNU development environment.  FreeRTOS has been ported to this platform and is a good stable base to work from.

There are also ARM Cortex-M3 parts that have the same capability and cheap/free tools.